# How to make a copy of a remote git branch (without merging with my existing branch)?

Tags: git, version-control

Suppose that I have been working on a `git repo` and the branch I'm working on is called `MyBranch`.

My co-worker tells me that he has something that I should pull from his branch on his `git repo`.  His branch is called `HisBranch`.

In order to do this, I type

```
git remote add MyCoworker $url
git checkout -b HisBranch
git pull MyCoworker HisBranch
```

When I do the git pull, it tells me that it is fetching data from the remote `repo` as intended, but since I created `HisBranch` locally by branching from `MyBranch`, it contains the same files and history as `MyBranch`, and git wants to merge the two together.

What I really want is to get a branch on my local `repo` that is identical to what I pulled from my co-workers branch, including the history.  I do not wish to immediately merge it with my own branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ git remote add MyCoworker $url
$ git fetch MyCoworker
```

It'll show sth like

> ...
>   * [new branch] HisBranch -> MyCoworker/HisBranch

then u can just check to his branch correctly:

```
$ git checkout HisBranch
```

---

B.t.w., if ur repo is the main repo to work on (ur co-work forks it to his own), then u need to ask him to send a Pull Request (a.k.a. PR) to u instead.

Comment: I find that a bit confusing because I'm used to making local branches with the same name as the remote and then pushing and pulling.  Is this an anti-pattern?

Comment: For example, I have a master branch, the remote has a master branch.  I make my changes to the master branch and then `git push origin master`

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon if u checkout new br based on ur local and do pulling, it'll merge the remote br to ur local one, this works if u'r the guy to submit the initial commit of that br. But if u want to checkout a pure br from other guy, u need to fetch from remote (MyCoworker in ur case) first.

Comment: And for ur 2nd e.g.: _"For example, ..."_ this's another case, cause both remote & local have the master br. So if u have a co-worker working w/ u, generally, u need to pull from master first ($ git pull origin master), then do push ($ git push origin master), here the origin is the common name used as our own repo's remote name.

Comment: For better understanding of the OP, u can think in this way, what u tried is to checkout new br based on ur own, but actually, ur co-worker already created one called HisBranch, so u just need to fetch the br from remote (MyCowoker) and switch to that br.